# Can I use TA-Lib in Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, finance

TA-Lib has a Java binary version.

http://ta-lib.org/hdr_dw.html

Can I use this in a Google App Engine project?

Comment: You might be the first person to try. Let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason that it wouldn't work would be the use of classes that are restricted in the production runtime.  Or the use of a library that uses one of those restricted classes.

You can get see list of classes that are allowed here:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html

There is also a list of frameworks and APIs that people have tested here:
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava

When you test this and find out, please update this question and the Will It Play wiki.